# Definition 3.15 from Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

I have one question from baby Rudin's definition on sequence that tends to $+\infty$.

**Definition:** Let $\{s_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers with the following property: For every real $M$ there is an integer $N$ such that $n\geqslant N$ implies $s_n\geqslant M$. We then write $$s_n\to+\infty$$

Can we change this definition to such?

For every real $M$ there is an integer $N$ such that $s_N\geqslant M$. Does it follow that $s_n\to+\infty$?

Comment: No, for example, define the sequence $s_n$ as $x$ (where $x$ is some fixed real number) if $n$ is odd and $n$ if $n$ is even. Does that sequence goes to $+\infty$?

Comment: Dear Carlos! This sequence is diverges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Here is a counterexample:
$$s_n = \begin{cases}n & \text{if }n\text{ is even} \\
0 & \text{if }n\text{ is odd} \\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks Bungo! Your post helped me.